# Links not working in Vue.js application when running npm run dev with Vite

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vite, npm-install

I'm encountering an issue with my Vue.js application where the links do not work properly when running npm run dev with Vite. Specifically, when I click on a link, the URL in the browser changes as expected, but the page does not navigate to the corresponding route. The issue occurs only during development with Vite; when I build the application using npm run build, the links work fine.

The stems from an another issue I had. Originally I was trying to build something using npm run build but every time I ran npm run build I would get an error saying my prop was not defined. Everything worked fine with npm run dev but when i did "npm run build" it would not work.

The code in question looked something like this

```
const props = defineProps({
    menuItemsProp: {type: Object},
    file_batches: Object,
    new_assignments: Number,
    unassigned_files: Number,
    status: String,
    monthly_reviews: Object,
    monthly_review_scores: Object,
    support_submissions: Object,
    assignments_in_progress: Number,
    assignments_past_due: Number,
    companies: Object,
    selected_company: {String, Number},
    tasks: Object,
});

const filterByCompany = () => {
  const currentRoute = route().current();
  // axios.get(`/admin/dashboard?company=${selectedCompany.value}`).then(response => {
  //   Inertia.reload();
  // });
  Inertia.get(
      route(currentRoute),
      {company: props.selected_company},
      {
        only: [props.refresh],
        preserveState: true,
      }
  );
};

<Select
            class="mb-10"
            name="company_filter"
            label="Filter by Company"
            :options="companies"
            v-model="selected_company"
            @change="filterByCompany" />
```

This would result in the error:
Reference Error: selected_company not defined.

again.. this worked just fine in npm run dev but not npm run build.

So i figured must be some sort of node issue. So I deleted node modules and lock file.. npm install..

which is where I am at now with the above issue where running npm run dev now links don't seem to work properly.

Really it is coming down to the fact that I do not understand node packages at all or how any of that works. It is the most frustrating thing being a developer as this seems like it is so overly complicated part of the process. Makes me want to leap off a high plateau.

If you can help great. If you want to be negative go away.

Thanks.

I have tried logging errors

I don't get any errors.. dev builds.. build builds... nothing in the console. Even when clicking the link that does not work it just does nothing. It shows the correct link in the browser address bar but won't go to that link until i manually click in and press enter.

Again.. everything was working with npm run dev before I deleted stuff and re installed node.

Comment: can you provide the ```.env``` file, ````app.js```` file, and ```vite.conf.js``` file?